# Two conditions based on subquery. How to shorten it?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have working query basing on 2 subqueries.

```sql
SELECT * FROM database1
where account_id in (SELECT account_id FROM (select account_id,transaction_id from ... here i have my big sql query))
and transaction_id in (SELECT transaction_id FROM (select account_id,transaction_id from ... here i have my big sql query))
```

I would like to know what to do to do not have to paste 2 times my big sql query and just use this two conditions in one line? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you really want:

```
select d.*
from database1 d
where exists (select 1
              from <big query here> q
              where q.account_id = d.account_id and
                    q.transaction_id = d.transaction_id
             );
```

Unlike your query, this guarantees that the two columns are on the *same row* in your query.  That is not what your query does, but I'm guessing it is your intention.

If you really want to check if either occurs anywhere, then you can use a CTE:

```
with q as (
      <your query here>
     )
select d.*
from database1 d
where exists (select 1 from q where q.account_id = d.account_id) and
      exists (select 1 from q where q.transaction_id = d.transaction_id);
```